# Set a description for an element (div) for a screenreader

Tags: html, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have an element (in bootstrap so positioned within a div) which contains a cookie statement (mandatory where I live, it sort of says 'we use cookies press ok')

Is there a way that I can say to the screen reader: the next `section/div/element` is a 'cookie statement?

So something like:

```
<div description = "This is a cookie statement">
```

I don't know how screenreaders work, but I can imagine then the user can decide to skip this `section/div/element`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markup defined by HTML, and understood by screen readers, to indicate what the next part of a document is about are the `<h1>` to `<h6>` series of heading elements. Screen readers typically include "Skip to next heading" features.

HTML also provides `<small>` to represent "side comments such as small print … disclaimers, caveats, legal restrictions, or copyrights".

```
<div>
    <h2>Cookie Usage Statement</h2>
    <p><small>Foo Inc. uses cookies for blah blah blah</small></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, that's nice. Thanks for the info about the 'Skip to next heading'

Comment: Read more about this topic in the very great guide about HTML5's semantic tags and what they mean for browsers, screenreaders and the end-user:
http://diveintohtml5.info/semantics.html

Answer (score -2):

You could add [`aria-hidden`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden) to the respective element.

Comment: That would conceal it from screen readers (and fail to meet the legal requirement to provide the message) rather than providing the *option* to skip it.